# Query Times : Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have a simple data loaded in Cloud Datastore. A "kind" with few "entities".
I am using [Cloud Datastore](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-datastore/1.40.0) Java client and I am consistently seeing a 100+ ms for the response times. 
The document is a simple string based key-value-pair data and is indexed. The higher SLAs were observed through the API explorer console as well as when running the client code in a cluster.

Is this SLA normal for the cloud datastore ?. I am looking for SLAs < ~50ms for a simple lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics of your project or the nature of the queries you're making, it's difficult to say whether these are normal response times. It's possible you can improve performance of your queries by following the guidelines that are laid out in the [Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#queries).

The latency of queries to Datastore is not currently covered by any [service level agreement (SLA)](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/sla).